# Table - Edit Mode (Sql 2008)

Tags: sql-server

In Object Explorer you can right click on a table and select Edit Top 200 Rows.  When you do it opens the table in Edit Mode.

Does anyone know the syntax of how to write that in a query so you do not have to right click and select Edit Top 200 Rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is not used to interact with the query tools like SQL Server Management Studio, which it sounds like you are using.

What you are after is something like a macro to automate a common task. I don't believe SQL Server Management Studio supports macros - the Express Edition certainly doesn't.